# Hive query to get the value for a given key in String

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I am using regexp_extract for getting sub-string from a string

My string is ":abd: 576892034 :erg: 94856023MXCI :oute: A RF WERS YUT :oowpo: 649217349GBT GB"

How will get this using regexp_extract function.

I need the value as **576892034** if i pass the key as **abd**
Any other function also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  regexp_extract(
    ':adb: 576892034 :erg: 94856023MXCI :oute: A RF WERS YUT :oowpo: 649217349GBT GB',
    ':oute: ((?:.(?!:))+)',
    1
  )
```

manual : [cloudera docs](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_string_functions.html#string_functions__regexp_extract)

example of regex : [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aKjwvp/4)

Comment: Thanks. can you please let me know what it will do(Just i want to understand the meaning of this)... 
([^ ]+)

Comment: `(` and `)` mark a group.  In this case it's the first (and only) group, which is why the `1` in the 3rd parameter of `regexp_extract` *(groups are used so that you can specify which part of the matching pattern you want to extract)*.  `[^ ]` means "any character that's not a space".  `+` means "at least one occurrence, but match as many as are found".  If you're still unclear, SO is the wrong place for this, you need to read a regular expression tutorial.

Comment: it is working fine but for this key :oute: i need this value--> A RF WERS YUT

Comment: Then you need to match any character except those followed by a colon...  `.` = anything `(?!:)` = not followed by a colon.  => `((.(?!:))+)`  I have updated the answer, and the regex101 demo.

Comment: Useful reading for you: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html